# Windows 7 System Restore Failed

Tags: windows-7, windows, restore, system-restore, windows-7-restore

[image]

I need to restore Windows 7, because I installed some software which ruined my PC. I see the error above.

I tried running the restore tool using administrator privileges, and disabled my antivirus, but it didn't work.

Also I have a software on my PC called [MyPC Backup](http://www.mypcbackup.com/), but I didn't install it, so I don't know how it got there. Maybe it is causing these errors?

All my Google Chrome extensions are gone as well.

Comment: When you do system restore it reboots the computer. Did you get this error before rebooting or after?

Comment: @Dilshod after rebooting

Comment: do you have any other restore points? can you do the earlier one?

Comment: @Dilshod i tried restoring to earlier points, didn't help, i still got the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have software on your computer that you didn't install it's a safe bet that it is malware.

Download [Malwarebytes Rootkit Removal Tool](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/malwarebytes-anti-rootkit/)and [Malwarebytes](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/malwarebytes-anti-malware/). It wouldn't hurt to download [The Microsoft Rootkit Removal Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/malware-removal.aspx) while you're at it.

Install them. Reboot your computer in safe mode and run the programs one at a time.

Comment: i have avg internet security 2013 installed on my pc, did a scan, found 1 malware, then i did like you said, installed all three, malwarebytes found 9 malwares! they say avg is the best out there, i have doubts now. I am not sure if my problem was caused by a malware or not, could a malware stop you from restoring your pc? anyway i removed all the software i installed yesterday, updated chrome and everything is working, so i guess i will vote up your answer and accept it since you fixed my laptop :)

Comment: Without actually seeing your computer I am only guessing, but in general, if your computer is acting strangely and Anti-Virus software cannot help you if you have a "rootkit". That is why running the scans in safe mode is the only way to catch the malicious software. The final piece of advice I'd give is to avoid downloading software/music/video from torrent sites that you cannot trust. This is akin to simply downloading viruses directly t oyour computer.

Comment: true, almost all of these viruses were located in vuze (torrent downloader) folder!