# Photoshop cs6 does not work anymore

Tags: windows-7, windows, adobe-photoshop, dll, photoshop-cs6

I have a windows 7, 64 bit. I had an [issue with my my pc](https://superuser.com/questions/608752/windows-7-system-restore-failed), i scan it with malwarebytes, it removed about 9 viruses, i can't tell you what was removed, i accidentally emptied the quarantine.

Since i removed the viruses, Photoshop wont start anymore, it said that [amtlib.dll](http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?amtlib) was missing. I downloaded that, but now it shows the following error.

[image]

What's the problem?

Comment: So after you *just* cleaned your system of viruses, you downloaded a random DLL from some site? Even if it was clean, do you know if that's the version the app requires? How about just reinstalling Photoshop?

Comment: I'm guessing it was a cracked (pirated) version of Photoshop, and Malwarebytes deleted the DLL, either because it was *actually* malicious (backdoored crack) or because MWB auto-removes "potentially unwanted" software.

Comment: @Karan dll-files.com is the most popular site for dlls, if not the only one, so its my only option, i'm trying to fix before reinstalling, it's a last option

Comment: Copy and replace `amtlib.dll` at other Adobe product.

Comment: this error means you downloaded the file wit the wrong CPU architectur (64Bit for a 32Bit product)

Comment: @STTR i thought about doing it, but i don't have other adobe products installed, well adobe reader x, but i don't know where it is located, it doesn't show in the properties, anyway issue fixed, i had to download 64 bit version

Comment: @magicandre1981 true! thanks a lot! i downloaded the 64 version and it worked, if you had answered my question instead of commenting i would have accepted  your answer and voted it up :)

Comment: @Fischer ok, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, the error code  0xc000007b means the DLL was a wrong CPU architecture, so get the correct one:

```
C:\Users\André>err 0xc000007b
# for hex 0xc000007b / decimal -1073741701
  STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT                                    ntstatus.h
# {Bad Image}
# %hs is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains
# an error. Try installing the program again using the
# original installation media or contact your system
# administrator or the software vendor for support.
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_NULL (0x0), Code 0x7b
# for hex 0x7b / decimal 123
  ERROR_INVALID_NAME                                             winerror.h
# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is
# incorrect.
# 2 matches found for "0xc000007b"
```

Answer (score -1):

A lot of people will download the Trial Version of Adobe CS6 and change the amtlib.dll file so the 30 day trial period is disabled.  When you run Malwarebytes, it will flag this altered amtlib.dll file as a potential virus and the user unwittingly removes it.  Now the Adobe Photoshop, Premiere Pro, or whatever program you had will not load and you get an error message saying the amtlib.dll file is missing. Simply replace the file and everything will be fine.  You don't have to uninstall and reinstall, just replace the missing amtlib.dll file.  If you don't have it, search the internet and download it.  It will be easy to find.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do the rollback to a former restore point. I had the same problem and simple restoring the file (which I had replaced earlier after a virus ate the real one along with a lot of other dlls) while MalwareBytes was closed down made everything work again.

Answer (score -1):

I just followed my initial install instructions and copy/pasted the 32 and 64 bit versions of the amtlib.dll file in the right folders. (only DW and PS for me, since those were the only two programs I opened and had the dll's deleted before I figured out what to do)

Next I went into Malware Exlcusions option in Malewarebytes|Settings and added the two Adobe folders (C:\Program Files\Adobe and C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe).  Maybe a bit aggressive (ie, could have just identified all of the individual amtlib files - ugh).

Answer (score -2):

Go into the MalwareBytes quarantine folder and restore all the files ("restore" means don't delete!). Shutdown MalwareBytes and don't open Photoshop yet.

Do a system restore to an earlier date just before installing MalwareBytes. Your Photoshop will run!

MalwareBytes goes after the `amtlib.dll` and BAK files, especially the ones installed with activators like kspiro and etc off torrent sites.